# Golang custom timeout solution

Tags: go, ssh, timeout

I need to create a custom timeout solution for `ssh.Dial`. I tried setting the timeout in the sshConfig, but it just doesn't work sometimes which causes the whole program to hang.

```
connection, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "X.X.X.X:22", sshConfig)
```

In some cases it times out, it works in other cases. But it stumbles on specific IPs and doesn't do *anything*. It just hangs the entire program.

So how would I go about coding "my own" timeout solution for this line of code?

Comment: instead of using ssh.Dial 
use DialTimeout 
e.g :- 
 listener, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", "192.xxx.x.xxx:8899", 10*time.Second)
 if err != nil {
  fmt.Printf("connection error ", err.Error())
 }
DialTimeout acts like Dial but takes a timeout.

Comment: I am curious at what makes the code hang. Would you please provide some more info on the situation?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the config takes a timeout. See: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#ClientConfig

in other words:

```
conn, err := ssh.Dail("tcp", "X.X.X.X:22", ssh.ClientConfig{Timeout: time.Second * 4})
```

Comment: It takes a timeout. It just doesn't respect it and will hang on some IPs indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Did this and it worked:

```
    c1 := make(chan bool, 1)
    go RunRequest(element, authInfo, c1)
    select {
        case <-c1:
        case <-time.After(time.Second * 4):
    }
```

The ssh.Dial was inside the RunRequest GoRoutine.

Comment: That doesn't timeout anything, and just leaves the hanging function running indefinitely, which may or may not be tying up system resources.

Comment: But it’s not “timing out” RunRequest if it’s blocked, it leaves it blocked indefinitely. If the timeout isn’t working, figure what’s blocked rather than ignoring it.